# separate run configurations for each project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This is driving me crazy.  I have two projects.  Each time I change the run configuration for one project it also changes it for the other.  How do you create a separate run configuration for each project so that when the project is selected and you hit run it executes?

Comment: Run configurations normally are separate. So what **exactly** are you changing?

Comment: I create two different php projects. The index page for project A is A.html and the index page for project B is B.html.  I right click on each project and create a A run config with A.html as index page and a B run config with B.html as index page.  Both run configs show up whenever I right click on a project and select properties.  Whichever one I set last is the one that's used for both projects